# When tableDnD is disabled it leaves residual css and I can't clear the css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

[tableDnD](https://github.com/isocra/TableDnD) (table Drag and Drop) is a jQuery plugin I'm using to be able to re-order rows in my html table. It's a pretty cool library, but the fact that you can click, drag, and drop rows -- disables the ability to select that row by clicking -- it thinks you might be starting a drag and drop, or doing a 0-distance drag.

So you can view my example here, and see what I'm talking about -- http://jsfiddle.net/du31ufts/5/

It starts off as disabled, so enable the row re-ordering and see the library. Then, try to select just one row in the middle. **The only way** the blue highlighting indicating selection **shows up is if you click outside the bounds of the table**, and thus you would only be able to select starting from the bottom or top, and not be able to select one row at a time. I need to select these rows to be able to copy-paste these rows into excel.

I've tried looking into the library itself and [detaching](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) `$('__dragtable_disable_text_selection__')`, I've tried jquerys [removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/) for unselectable, I've tried

```
$('.dragtable-sortable').attr('-moz-user-select', 'none');
```

Nothing is re-enabling my ability to be able to click and select single rows. I'd like to do this without modifying tableDnD functions.

Which CSS properties could  be affecting my ability to select table rows?

Comment: Yes I can select the headers but that's not useful information, but the data is what's important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [asked about this on github](https://github.com/isocra/TableDnD/issues/43#issuecomment-61266976) and got an answer: It did require modification of the library. Specifically, replacing the if block starting at line 207 of the fiddle in this question with this

```
if (!$(this).hasClass("nodrag")) {
    if (e.target.tagName == "TD") {
        $.tableDnD.initialiseDrag(this, table, this, e, config);
    return false;
    }
}
```

[modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/du31ufts/6/). Thank you [tschqr](https://github.com/tschqr)

Answer (score 1):

Create a textarea somewhere with ID #spot.
Use this code to extract data on click from a row and select it. Its delimited by tab so it should be pastable into excel easily.

```
$('tr').click(function(){
    var copyContent = "";
    $(this).children('td').each(function(){
        copyContent = copyContent+$(this).text()+"\t";
    });
    $('#spot').val(copyContent);
    $('#spot').select();
});
```

Comment: As clever as this answer is, it still doesn't allow me to select rows. What if I need to select two rows to copy-paste? It's extremely clever but it's more of a workaround than a solution